# Show all unique elements in a list and how many times they appeared

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a formula that would return me a list of all unique elements in a list and how many times each appeared. I can't predict what is going to be added to the list, but it is a list of strings.

Example:

```
Car
Car
Bike
Car
Bus
Bus
```

Would result in:

```
Bike 1
Bus 2
Car 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a job for a Pivot Table!

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: PS: I am trying to rank everyone that submitted an entry to the excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create unique list, paste below formula to `C2` and enter as array formula, `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. Then drag down to copy.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$7), 0))
```

Then use COUNTIF, paste to `D2`, then drag down to copy:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,C2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or try Data - Consolidate
[image]

Just insert number 1 in column right.

Than choose as in picture. [image]

When press ok you'll get

[image]